# Regular expressions in ExpressJS Route

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js, rest, express

In ExpressJS, how do I write the following in one route using RegEx?

```
/api/projects/{id} and /api/projects&limit=5
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I'd do it.  Though it's not using RegEx, nor is it using just ONE route technically.

```
router.get('/api/projects/:id', handleRoute)
router.get('/api/projects', handleRoute)
```

in `handleRoute` you'd have to deal with the query param.  I'm not aware of any other ways to trigger a route based on the query param.  Maybe someone else can chime in if I missed something.